# Quickest way of checking JSON equivalence

Tags: javascript, json

I have two web services generating JSON output. Both services are using different technologies but are supposed to generate the exact same output.

I want to check if this output is exactly the same in the browser environment. I would really prefer to simple compare them as string, but the JSON output is not sorted.

I can convert JSON string to objects and then iterate over their keys to check the equivalence but that is basically a n^2 algorithm.

I was wondering if there is any quicker or better way. Something that browser environment already provides.

Comment: No, the browser does not provide a deep equality check. You can write your own, however: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13142968/139010

Comment: It's worth mentioning that that probably won't be an O(n^2) algorithm because key accesses in JavaScript are constant-time. Iterate the keys in object A and make sure each exists (and matches) in object B, then iterate object B checking against object A. No need for a nested loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no such method provided by the browsers to do a deep comparison. WE have to do it ourselves or using some non native library.