# Array creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This might be a rather silly question, but I am having some troubles with arrays in Javascript right now. Namely, why is this:

```
var data = new Array(new Array('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

not equal to this:

```
var data2 = [['a', 'b', 'c']];
```

If I compare both arrays and print out the result it says `false`. Why is that?

```
alert(data2==data);
>false
```

and much more confusing, if I create a third data array as data2 and name it data3, why is it still returning `false` when I compare both?

```
var data3 = [['a', 'b', 'c']];
alert(data2==data3);
>false
```

Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: You're comparing references, not values.

Comment: Every new array - is a new object with its own reference. That's why even `[]==[]` returns `false`.

Comment: If you want to compare different arrays content's then have a look at this accepted answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142968/deep-comparison-of-objects-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Here is another comprehensive answer on the subject:

[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

The basic gist of how that code implements array equality is looping through both and checking piece by piece to see if each index of the array is equal.