# Mongoose Update only changed data fields in multiple nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection which looks like this

```
{
   "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399afe",
   "basics":{
      "location":{
         "_id":"5f576a397775e75af4399b00",
         "address":"2712 Broadway St",
         "postalCode":"CA 94115",
         "city":"San Francisco",
         "countryCode":"US",
         "region":"California",
         "hidden":"false"
      },
      "name":"John Doe",
      "label":"Programmer",
      "picture":"",
      "email":"john@gmail.com",
      "phone":"(912) 555-4321",
      "website":"http://johndoe.com",
      "summary":"A summary of John Doe...",
      "profiles":[
         {
            "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399aff",
            "network":"Twitter",
            "username":"john",
            "url":"http://twitter.com/john",
            "hidden": false
         }
      ]
   },
   "work":[
      {
         "highlights":[
            "Started the company"
         ],
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b00",
         "company":"Company",
         "position":"President",
         "website":"http://company.com",
         "startDate":{
            "$date":"2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "endDate":{
            "$date":"2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "summary":"Description...",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "volunteer":[
      {
         "highlights":[
            "Awarded 'Volunteer of the Month'"
         ],
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b01",
         "organization":"Organization",
         "position":"Volunteer",
         "website":"http://organization.com/",
         "startDate":{
            "$date":"2012-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "endDate":{
            "$date":"2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "summary":"Description...",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "education":[
      {
         "courses":[
            "DB1101 - Basic SQL",
            "MTH 511 - Algorithmic Mathematics"
         ],
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b02",
         "institution":"University",
         "area":"Software Development",
         "studyType":"Bachelor",
         "startDate":{
            "$date":"2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "endDate":{
            "$date":"2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "gpa":"4.0",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "awards":[
      {
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b03",
         "title":"Award",
         "date":{
            "$date":"2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "awarder":"Company",
         "summary":"There is no spoon.",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "publications":[
      {
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b04",
         "name":"Publication",
         "publisher":"Company",
         "releaseDate":{
            "$date":"2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
         },
         "website":"http://publication.com",
         "summary":"Description...",
         "highlights":[
            "Wrote this paper"
         ],
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "skills":[
      {
         "keywords":[
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "Javascript"
         ],
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b05",
         "name":"Web Development",
         "level":"Master",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "languages":[
      {
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b06",
         "language":"English",
         "fluency":"Native speaker",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "interests":[
      {
         "keywords":[
            "Ferrets",
            "Unicorns"
         ],
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b07",
         "name":"Wildlife",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "references":[
      {
         "_id":"5f573a697775e75af4399b08",
         "name":"Jane Doe",
         "reference":"Reference...",
         "hidden": false
      }
   ],
   "__v":0
}
```

I have an api that responds with a json like this

```
{
    "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399afe",
    "quickText": "John Doe",
    "hidden": false,
    "location": [
        {
            "_id":"5f576a397775e75af4399b00",
            "quickText": "2712 Broadway St",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "profiles": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399aff",
            "quickText": "Twitter",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "work": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b00",
            "quickText": "Company / President",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "volunteer": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b01",
            "quickText": "Organization / Volunteer",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "education": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b02",
            "quickText": "University / Software Development",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "publications": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b04",
            "quickText": "Publication",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "awards": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b03",
            "quickText": "Award",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b05",
            "quickText": "Web Development",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b06",
            "quickText": "English",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "interests": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b07",
            "quickText": "Wildlife",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "id": "5f573a697775e75af4399b08",
            "quickText": "Jane Doe",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ]
}
```

On the frontend user changes values of `hidden` fields to either `true` or `false` and returns the same json object with updated `hidden` fields.

Now, how can I update only the changed values in NodeJS Mongoose, i.e. some `hidden` fields are changed from `true` to `false` and vice-versa.

I am working with [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) but couldn't figure it out for my scenario. As you may also see, `location` and `profiles` are nested within `basics`, however others are outside as in schema.

This is my route and login,

```
router.post('/hidden/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  let changedResume = req.body
  if(changedResume.profiles.length) {
    console.log('there is profile')
    changedResume.profiles.forEach(elem => {
      console.log(elem)
      Resume.findByIdAndUpdate(
        { "_id" : new ObjectId(changedResume.id), "basics.profiles._id": new ObjectId(elem.id)},
        { "$set": { "basics.profiles.$[element].hidden": elem.hidden}},
        { "arrayFilters": [{"element._id": new ObjectId(elem.id)}], "upsert": true}, 
        function(err, docs) {
          if (err){ 
            console.log(err) 
          } 
          else{ 
              console.log("Updated User : ", docs); 
          } 
        }
        )
    })
  }
```

With this controller I'll have to go through all arrays (above only shows for profiles) one by one and update all which was not even changed by user. Is there any other way I can update only the changed data?

Refereces:

- [how to get only the “changed” values from two JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295545/how-to-get-only-the-changed-values-from-two-json-objects) - this gives javascript code to get the difference between two object (json or array), but only gives what's changed, in my case it'll only return value of `hidden`, with no `id`s.

  ```
   {"languages":[{"hidden":true}],"interests":[{"hidden":true}]}
  ```