# Duplicate sub arrays

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array (generated dynamically) which contains  objects. Those objects contains arrays which sometimes are duplicated.

I wonder how could I make a function to check the arrays contained in the objects to see if they're duplicated.

In javascript.

Tried using the following function, but it will only check the objects in the first sub-array. Won't work on other sub-arrays.

```
var check = function (a){
                var retval = [];
                for (var j = 0, u = a.length; j < u; j++) {
                    if (a[j].items && a[j].items.length > 1){

                        check(a[j].items);
                    }
                    for (var k = j + 1, v = a.length; k < v; k++) {
                        if (a[j] && a[k]){
                            if (a[j]._id == a[k]._id) {

                            }
                            else{
                                retval.push(a[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return retval;
            };
```

Comment: Please provide us what you have tried, including sufficient data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep comparison of objects/arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142968/deep-comparison-of-objects-arrays)

Comment: No duplicate. @GeorgeJempty, edited main post.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recusion for this.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/89agjx2c/

```
var init = function(){
  var one = new Array();
  var two = new Array();

  root = new Array();
  root.push(one);
  root.push(two);

  var one_one = {'id': 1, 'name':"one_one"};
  var one_two = {'id': 2, 'name':"one_two"};

  var two_one = {'id': 3, 'name':"one_two"};
  var two_two = {'id': 1, 'name':"one_one"};

  one.push(one_one);
  one.push(one_two);

  two.push(two_one);
  two.push(two_two);
}

this.check = function(_array){
  for (var element in _array) { 
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( _array[element] ) === '[object Array]'){
            // Found an array
      this.check(_array[element]);
    } else{
      // Found an object
      toCheck = JSON.stringify(_array[element]);
      counter = 0;

            this.checkDuplicates(root, toCheck);
            if(counter == 2){
        console.log("duplicate found for item: " + toCheck)
      }
    }
  }
}

this.checkDuplicates = function(_array, toCheck){
  for (var element in _array) { 
    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( _array[element] ) === '[object Array]'){
            // Found an array
      this.checkDuplicates(_array[element], toCheck);
    } else{
      // Found an object
      if(JSON.stringify(_array[element]) === toCheck){
        counter++;
      }
    }
  }
}

init();
check(root);
```