# Compare 2 arrays in javascript and extract differences

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array 1 is the result of the data from a localstorage

Array 2 is, for the same IDs (329, 307, 355), the result after treatment

So i need to compare both to notify what changed

**Array 1 :**

```
[{"329":["45738","45737","45736"]},{"307":["45467","45468"]},{"355":["47921"]}]
```

**Array 2 :**

```
[{"355":["47921","45922"]},{"329":["45738","45737","45736"]},{"307":[]}]
```

I need to compare Array 2 with Array 1 and extract differences.

In this example i want to have for result

```
[{"355":["45922"]},{"307":[]}]
```

I try to adapt this code :

```
var compareJSON = function(obj1, obj2) {
  var ret = {};
  for(var i in obj2) {
    if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i) || obj2[i] !== obj1[i]) {
      ret[i] = obj2[i];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};
```

Runnable:

```js
var array1 = [{
    "329": ["45738", "45737", "45736"]
  }, {
    "307": ["45467", "45468"]
  }, {
    "355": ["47921"]
  }],
  array2 = [{
    "355": ["47921", "45922"]
  }, {
    "329": ["45738", "45737", "45736"]
  }, {
    "307": []
  }]

var compareJSON = function(obj1, obj2) {
  var ret = {};
  for (var i in obj2) {
    if (!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i) || obj2[i] !== obj1[i]) {
      ret[i] = obj2[i];
    }
  }
  return ret;
};

console.log(compareJSON(array1, array2));
```

But, either I have nothing or I have the whole table

Comment: why are in the result in `307` no items?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "extract differences"? I'm not sure exactly  what rules produced the result for your example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as **too broad** because the code would likely need to be modified significantly in order to achieve the expected results

Comment: `obj2[i] !== obj1[i]` is comparing arrays. Note that in Javascript: **`[] !== []`**. So that test is probably returning `false` all the time.

Comment: @Sweater-Baron i need to show differences between the 2 arrays

Comment: @bklups why is `307` empty after?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir need to show differences between the 2 arrays

Comment: ^^^ it's not an answer, why is 307 included in the result with an empty array?

Comment: First of all `obj1` and `obj2` will be `array1` and `array2` respectively.

Comment: Could you include what the desired returned array would look like to make sure we all understand what you are looking for?

Comment: @JoeLissner the expected output is already posted, and that's the problem because it's doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir thanks, sorry, didn't see it before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep comparison of objects/arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142968/deep-comparison-of-objects-arrays)

Comment: I edited to add more explications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your requirement(result) is not clear, but this will get you started.

```js
var arr1 = [{ "329": ["45738", "45737", "45736"] }, { "307": ["45467", "45468"] }, { "355": ["47921"] }],
  arr2 = [{ "355": ["47921", "45922"] }, { "329": ["45738", "45737", "45736"] }, { "307": [] }];

var result = [];

arr2.forEach(obj => {
  var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  var match = arr1.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty(key));
  if (match) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[key] = obj[key].filter(s => match[key].indexOf(s) === -1);
    if (!obj[key].length || newObj[key].length) result.push(newObj)
  } else {
    result.push(Object.assign({}, obj));
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just before the end of forEach i need to update `arr1` with data of `arr2`. So when i reload, `newObj` is reset to 0 (so, no differences yet). But is there a way to store differences in a variable, and concatenate it every time there are new differences ? I try to push in an array but it overwrites it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash tbale and delete found items. If some items remains, then an empty array is taken to the result object.

```js
var array1 = [{ 329: ["45738", "45737", "45736"] }, { 307: ["45467", "45468"] }, { 355: ["47921"] }],
    array2 = [{ 355: ["47921", "45922"] }, { 329: ["45738", "45737", "45736"] }, { 307: [] }],
    hash = {},
    result = [];

array1.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        hash[k] = hash[k] || {};
        o[k].forEach(function (a) {
            hash[k][a] = true;
        });
    });
});

array2.forEach(function (o) {
    var tempObject = {};
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        var tempArray = [];
        o[k].forEach(function (a) {
            if (hash[k][a]) {
                delete hash[k][a];
            } else {
                tempArray.push(a);
            }
        });
        if (tempArray.length || Object.keys(hash[k]).length) {
            tempObject[k] = tempArray;
        }
    });
    Object.keys(tempObject).length && result.push(tempObject);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [deep-diff package](https://github.com/flitbit/diff) in npm for this sort of thing before:

It may be more detail than you want though - here's an example from the readme of the output format:

```
[ { kind: 'E',
  path: [ 'name' ],
  lhs: 'my object',
  rhs: 'updated object' },
{ kind: 'E',
  path: [ 'details', 'with', 2 ],
    lhs: 'elements',
    rhs: 'more' },
{ kind: 'A',
  path: [ 'details', 'with' ],
  index: 3,
  item: { kind: 'N', rhs: 'elements' } },
{ kind: 'A',
  path: [ 'details', 'with' ],
  index: 4,
  item: { kind: 'N', rhs: { than: 'before' } } } ]
```

Checkout the readme on the github page linked above for details about what it all means, or [try it out for yourself online using runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/deep-diff)

But in order for this to work you would have to do some sort of preprocessing:

### Sort array based on first key of each element:

```
a1 = a1.sort((lhs, rhs) => {
  return parseInt(Object.keys(lhs)[0]) - parseInt(Object.keys(rhs)[0]);
})
```

If you sort both of the arrays by the first key of each element and then pass it to the diff tool, you get the following:

```
[
  {"kind":"A","path":[0,"307"],"index":0,"item":{"kind":"D","lhs":"45467"}},
  {"kind":"A","path":[0,"307"],"index":1,"item":{"kind":"D","lhs":"45468"}},
  {"kind":"A","path":[2,"355"],"index":1,"item":{"kind":"N","rhs":"45922"}}
]
```

If it were me I would probably merge all the array elements and diff the resulting object so you completely avoid any object order and duplicate key issues.

### Alternative: merge array contents into one object

A naive merge might look like this:

```
a1Object = {}

a1.forEach((element) => { 
    Object.keys(element).forEach((key) => {
        a1Object[key] = element[key];
    });
})
```

Which produces the following diff:

```
[
  {"kind":"A","path":["307"],"index":0,"item":{"kind":"D","lhs":"45467"}},
  {"kind":"A","path":["307"],"index":1,"item":{"kind":"D","lhs":"45468"}},
  {"kind":"A","path":["355"],"index":1,"item":{"kind":"N","rhs":"45922"}}
]
```

### Interpreting the diff output

- there is a change in the `A`rray value of `307` at index `0`: `45467` has been `D`eleted
- there is a change in the `A`rray value of `307` at index `1`: `45468` has been `D`eleted
- there is a change in the `A`rray value of `355` at index `1`: `45467` has been `N`ewly added